# Swift generic bool casting different from direct casting

Tags: swift, generics

```
let dic: [String: Any] = [
    "b": true
]

func cast<T>(value: Any, to type: T) -> T? {
    return value as? T
}

let value = dic["b"]!
let casted = cast(value: value, to: Bool.self)

print(casted.debugDescription) // nil
print(value as! Bool) // true
```

I'm doing dynamic casting using generic function, the results are different from direct casting when the value is `Bool`, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `type` correctly as below,

```
func cast<T>(value: Any, to type: T.Type) -> T?
```

**OR**

You can remove passing the `type` as below,

```
func cast<T>(value: Any) -> T? {
    return value as? T
}

let casted: Bool? = cast(value: value)
```